# Working With mupdf in android studio

Tags: android, android-studio, android-ndk, noclassdeffounderror, mupdf

I am working with **mupdf** library for rendering pdf files in my android application using **Android Studio** as IDE.

I have compiled **mupdf** library using **ndk** and **cygwin** and integrated in my application also.

Now when i trying to run my application , i a getting some errors here.

I would like to share it with you.
If some one able to crack me out.

[This](http://pastebin.com/9gxE7LMj) is the error log.

Thanks guys.